# Emacs command history including commands called by keys and with arguments passed to them

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp

Is there a way to show full command history with arguments?

`repeat-complex-command` which is bound to:

```
<again>, <redo>, C-x M-:, C-x M-ESC
```

does not show commands that are invoked from key bindings, and `kmacro-edit-macro` (which is bound to `C-x C-k RET`) does not show arguments passed to commands.

Motivation. It would make it faster to turn a keyboard macro into an elisp function. For now, I invoke `kmacro-edit-macro` to see names of commands to use and then work out what arguments to pass by reading documentation of commands one by one. (Example workflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24784563/1446335)

Note. It is possible to programmatically press key sequence from within an elisp function, but its usefulness is small.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to get what you want, use `pre-command-hook` to invoke a function that adds the given command to `extended-command-history`.  For example, this is what the [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles) code does to add commands executed by menu to this history:

```
;; This is done when you turn on Icicle mode.
(if icicle-menu-items-to-history-flag
    (add-hook 'pre-command-hook 'icicle-add-menu-item-to-cmd-history)
  (remove-hook 'pre-command-hook 'icicle-add-menu-item-to-cmd-history))

(defun icicle-add-menu-item-to-cmd-history ()
  "Add `this-command' to command history, if it is a menu item.
Menu items that are not associated with a command symbol are ignored.
Used on `pre-command-hook'."
  (condition-case nil                   ; Just in case, since this is on `pre-command-hook'.
      (when (and (> (length (this-command-keys-vector)) 0)
                 (equal '(menu-bar) (elt (this-command-keys-vector) 0))
                 ;; Exclude uninterned symbols such as `menu-function-356'.
                 (symbolp this-command) (or (< emacs-major-version 21)  (intern-soft this-command)))
        (pushnew (symbol-name this-command) extended-command-history))
    (error nil)))
```

Comment: Is there a way to extract the arguments passed to the command? Maybe a function whose good name could be `this-command-args`?

Comment: @JisangYoo I don't think so, but I might be forgetting something - someone will correct me if I'm wrong. You could maybe try playing with global variable `values` at some point. But I doubt that would help, because the code that has access to the complete command (function + actual args) is the C code for `call-interactively` in `callint.c`. But you can of course advise any *particular* command to get access to its actual args.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great to have a way to turn a keyboard-macro into a chunk of Elisp code, but for this chunk of Elisp code to be useful, it should be somewhat idiomatic, yet in many cases, the idiomatic Elisp code to do something is quite different from the keyboard-macro way to do it (e.g. idiomatic code should not use the mark and the kill ring just to extract and move text around).

So the transcription is not straightforward.  I think the way to write such a thing is to "start small" and accept the fact that it will not be 100% reliable.